# Populate Listbox using DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, ms-access, listbox

I'm trying to populate my listbox with information from Access, am I doing it right? or am I missing a few things. Because when I search my listbox isn't being populated. I'm using a DateTimePicker as my search to look for specific dates and all information relating to it to be displayed.

```
try
{
    connection.Open();
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
    command.Connection = connection;
    string query = "SELECT *FROM Booking WHERE Date=" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "";
    command.CommandText = query;
    OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(reader["CID"].ToString());
        listBox1.Items.Add(reader["VehicleNumber"].ToString());
        listBox1.Items.Add(reader["Date"].ToString());
        listBox1.Items.Add(reader["Time"].ToString());
    }
    connection.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
}
```

Comment: Looks like a textbox, not DTP.  Read up on SQL parameters - they will make your life simpler and the code more readable and manageable as well as protect against SQL injection attacks.

Comment: For each element you find you seem to add 4 rows into your listbox. Is that what you wanted to achieve because that seems kind of odd. Did you try to set a break point at the 11 of your snippet and if yes did it got hit. Do you get a message box with an error?

Comment: mm, how would I add columns into here, along with My datetimepicker would be displayed onto textbox, i know it seems kind of odd. But I thought it'd be simpler to get it from the db then.

Comment: A textbox cannot hold a `DateTime` var, where as `myDTP.Value` **is** a `DateTime` type.  Presumably the db column is `Date` so you should pass a `Date`.

Comment: Alright I changed the query, to 
`string query = "SELECT *FROM Booking WHERE Date=" + dateTimePicker1.Valuet + "";` but it isn't populating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a proper format for the string expression of the date value:

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM Booking WHERE [Date] = #" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") + "#";
```

Comment: But what if I'm using a default dtp format? Example, Sunday, 29 May ,2016 will; that format still work?

Comment: The value of the picker is _DateTime_ which carries no format, it is numeric. A format is applied only for display.

Comment: So I use a seperate query?

Comment: No - though I don't understand the question.

Comment: I'm using a dateTimePicker, to select specific dates made from bookings in my database. So the ReportViewer will be able to generate on specific dates rather than the whole database. Right now, I've tried inserting into the DataAdapter with From @from etc, but my query didn't want to allow the symbol @, not quite sure why. So I've decided to just use that query in my form. Right now, my query is displaying one data and nothing else, even if I do add other dates into the database, it shows only for one specific date and it won't change. I'm not sure why, is my query clashing with my dataset.

Comment: Sorry if I'm complicating things.

Comment: If you now receive data from one date only (from the DateTimePicker), your original question seems solved. If you have other issues, you should open a new question.